Cypress test catching the wrong request
I'm trying to catch a request, but others are raised on the same page.
I want to get the second request, but apparently the third overwrites the intercept
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.visit("/portal/grafico");
  });
  
it("Deve interceptar a requisição e verificar se ela é válida quando clicar no select do gráfico Percentual de municípios por faixa de matrículas em tempo integral e inse", () => {
    cy.wait(1000);
    cy.intercept({
      method: "GET",
      url: `${apiUrl}/api/distribuicao-municipio-faixa-matricula/?ano=2022`,
    }).as("apiRequest");

    cy.get('[data-testid="selectPrincipalGraficos"]').click();
    cy.get("ul.p-dropdown-items")
    .should("be.visible")

    .contains(
        "Percentual de municípios por faixa de matrículas em tempo integral e inse"
    )
    .should("be.visible")
    .click();

    cy.wait("@apiRequest").then((interception) => {
      if (interception.response) {
        expect(interception.response.statusCode).to.eq(200);
      }
    });
  });



If you look at the Cypress log, the fetch you want to intercept occurs after the wait(1000) and before the click().
This means that the fetch is triggered on loading the page, not by the click.
But your cy.intercept() is set up after the page load, which is too late to intercept the fetch.
Simply by moving the intercept into the beforeEach() should allow you to catch the fetch you want.
 beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept({
      method: "GET",
      url: `${apiUrl}/api/distribuicao-municipio-faixa-matricula/?ano=2022`,
    }).as("apiRequest");

    cy.visit("/portal/grafico");
  });
  
it("Deve interceptar a requisição ...", () => {
  ...
  cy.wait("@apiRequest")...

